# end-of-the-word regular expression for mixed language words (in python2)

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I need to find a regex in a text combined from english AND other unicode letters.

The problem is - word boundary is incorrect for mixed-language:

```
text: הmאפrקt boom sam
regex: m\b
also tried: m(?=\W)
```

Desired result: capture only the "m" in "boom" and "sam", not in the 1st word.

In practice, however, the "m\b" regex matches all of the "m" letters in the text. This is wrong (from my perspective) since the first "m" is in the middle of a word.

I managed to use an ugly lookahead like this, which is a working solution:

```
(?=$|[^a-zא-ת])
```

meaning: it looks either for an end-of-the-sentence, or any other non-english-non-hebrew letters, but doesn't consume it.

But this is not a full solution: it doesn't deal with diacritic marks, or other letters in other languages;

Is there a more elegant way to deal with mixed multi-lingual word boundaries in python2 regular expressions?

my code sample:

```
text = ur"הmאפrקt boom sam"
result = re.sub(ur'm\b', 'X', text, flags=re.I+re.M+re.S)

result is: "הXאפrקt booX saX"
should be: "הmאפrקt booX saX"
```

**solution**

thanks to viktor's answer; provided that all strings are unicode:

```
text = re.sub(oldtext, replacement, text, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: Please show all the relevant Python code you have.

Comment: Aha, you are replacing, I will add the `re.sub` example to my answer.

Comment: you should rename your question to end-of-the-world regular expression... lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile the regex with `re.UNICODE` flag to make `\b` Unicode-aware. Also, keep in mind that all the strings you are using must be Unicode.

Here is how you may fix your *replacing* code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
text = ur"הmאפrקt boom sam"
result = re.sub(ur'm\b', u'X', text, 0, re.UNICODE).encode("utf8")
print(result)
```

See the [online Python 2 demo](https://ideone.com/wttpta).

Here is a *matching* snippet:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
s = "הmאפrקt sam"
match = re.search(ur'\w*m\b', s.decode('utf8'), flags=re.UNICODE)
if match:
    print(match.group(0).encode("utf8"))
```

And an example with `re.findall` proves there is only one match:

```
print([x.encode("utf8") for x in re.findall(ur'\w*m\b', s.decode('utf8'), flags=re.UNICODE)])
# => ['sam']
```

See the [Python 2 online demo](https://ideone.com/YXKK4v).